# Showing a set is closed or open in $\mathbb{R^d}$

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set is closed or open in $\mathbb{R^d}$ 
, where u is a fixed non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R^d}$

{${x \in \mathbb{R^d} : ⟨x, u⟩=5}$}

So I know that any closed set has the following property:

A set is closed iff it contains all of its limit points

But I don't see how I could use this property here? I don't want an answer but if someone could explain how I'd go about proving this or similar problems it would really be appreciated. This topology unit in general is sort of ruining my life.

Comment: So to show that your set $A$ contains its limit points, prove that if $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $A$ then its limit $x$ is a point of $A$. This amounts to proving that if $x_n\to x$ and each $\left<x_n,u\right>=5$ then $\left<x,u\right>=5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\langle x,u \rangle$. Clearly, this function is continuous and your set can be written as
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d :\, \langle x,u \rangle=5\} = f^{-1}(\{5\})$$
and since $\{5\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, it follows that your set is also closed in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: How did you know to do that though? Like I feel like there is just so many different theorems and definitions and stuff that I'm overwhelmed.

Comment: A function $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous if and only if for every closed set $K\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^m$ we have that $f^{-1}(K)$ is also closed. It is probably not something you have seen and this answer does not solve anything.